# How to get a list of items from a particular folder

Tags: powershell, metadata, csv

The Following code write all the items from the list to CSV file.

```
$list.Items| foreach {
            $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                     "Title" = $_["Title"]
                     "Name" = $_["Name"]
                     "Modified Date" = $_["Modified"]
                     "Modified By" =$_["Modified By"]
                     "Size"= $_["File Size"]
                     "Path" = $web.Url + "/" + $_.File.Url

    }
    $exportlist += $obj
    $exportlist | Export-Csv -path $destinationfolder/'Folder.csv' -noType
    }
```

How to write only items contain in particular folder into CSV file.
For example I have folder name Test inside my document library.folder contains many documents.i just want items which are inside Test into CSV file and not the whole list items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `SPQuery` object and set its `Folder` property and then call `GetItems` on List and finally loop through the item collection.

```
$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$spQuery.Folder = $folder;
$items = $list.GetItems($spQuery);
```